# how to plot single column data in spreadsheet using app script

Tags: javascript, charts, plot, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to plot data which is saved in a single column in a spreadsheet, I had adopt some code it work with no error, but it does not show the chart?and this is some data samples:

0.03349031881

-0.02930402942

-0.1004709601

-0.1716378927

-0.1130298302

....

...

```
 function doGet(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var data = sheet.getRange('A1:A1000').getValues();

  //Build data table
  var dataTable = Charts.newDataTable();

  //Add columns
   dataTable.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, data[0][0]);

  //Add rows
  for(var j=1; j<data.length; j++){
    dataTable.addRow(data[j]);
    Logger.log(data[j])
  }

  //Create and build chart
  var chart = Charts.newBarChart()
      .setDataTable(dataTable)
      .setTitle("my Data")
      .build();

  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Some Title");
  app.add(chart)
  return app;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to run this from a spreadsheet or as a standalone webapp ?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the active spreadsheet generally won't work from doGet because it relies on the spreadsheet being open and therefore won't be active. You would want to get the sheet by name or id instead.